# Why is IIS hosted angular 8 app serving strange JavaScript content?

Tags: angular, iis

I have an angular 8 app, it works on my machine. But when I build it and deploy it to IIS, I get a blank page, but what’s weird is that it’s serving my JavaScript in a foreign language:

⨯⨪⨪⼪⠠畦据楴湯洨摯汵獥 ⁻⼯眠扥慰正潂瑯瑳慲ੰ⨯⨪⨪⼪ठ⼯椠獮慴汬愠䨠

Polyfill.bundle.js: 敷灢捡䩫潳灮嬨瀢汯晹汩獬崢第ਊ⨯⨪ ⸢⼮⸮ⸯ⼮⸮ⸯ⼮牳⽣潰祬楦汬⹳獴㨢⼊⨪⼪
But opening the file, or downloading it in another tab shows:

```
webpackJsonp(["polyfills"],{

/***/ "../../../../../src/polyfills.ts":
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {
```

I then point the IIS application to the dist folder from IIS the site it works. But if I copy the files else where and host them I get the problem above. At one point, I copied files from dist to problem location and the file changed from html to the above. I had to copy and paste the file contents before it displayed properly in vs code. But in IIS it still served the above.

Am I missing something really obvious? Anyone seen this before? Could it be disk issues? Some of that text translates like "soup soup".

[image: screenshot of what's displayed]

I've run `ng build --base-href /client/` in Azure DevOps, deployed the application but it displays the same symptoms. However, when I point IIS to the manually built ng dist folder, it works. If I copy that path somewhere else, I get the above text

Comment: you could use ng build command to build an application for that first enter to the folder using command prompt and run this command. it will create a dist folder under your project folder. open iis and point the dist folder as the folder path when you add site. did you try to put the dist folder to another location expect the problem folder?

Comment: Yes. I've updated question. I don't think it's related to angular at all. When I copied and pasted files to replace the broken files, the contents changed to the above!

Comment: it looks like the disk-related issue, not iis.